# Have to read object values twice in adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an adapter which i have to load into Aphid-FlipView Api. I have to load values from object and fill it into XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rssImage"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rssTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rssImage2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rssTitle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The adapter works reading one value at a time from the object, but i have to read two objects and pass its value to the layout. How would i do it?

```
private List<CNN> objects;
ImageView iv;
private Context context;


public CNNArrayAdapter(Context context, int listview1, List<CNN> result) {
    super(context, listview1, result);
    this.objects=result;
    this.context = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rssTitle);
     iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.rssImage);
     TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rssTitle2));
     ImageView iv2 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.rssImage2);      
    CNN i = objects.get(position);
    CNN i2 = objects.get(position+1);
    if(i!=null)
    {
                if (tt != null){
                    tt.setText(i.getTitle());
                }
                if (iv != null){                    
                    Picasso.with(context).load(i.getImgURL()).into(iv);
                }
            if(i2!=null)
            {
                tt.setText(i2.getTitle());
            }
    }
    return v;
}
```

This Code would cause duplicates in ListView.Hope you get my point.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear

Comment: `position+1` might be out of bounds, please use an if statement to ensure your code does not crash.

Comment: I have List<objects> in my code. getView() Method reads one object by position i.e. CNN i = object.get(position) but i have to read 'two objects' values in getView() method and pass it to layout.

Comment: How i avoid OutOfBounds Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to use two object per item...

However, to do that, do the following.

Fiert you need to be sure, or assume, the datas you want to diplsay are in even number.

Override the `getCount` method of your adapter.

```
public int getCount() {
     return objects.size() / 2;
}
```

Change the following lines in `getView` method

```
CNN i = objects.get(position);
CNN i2 = objects.get(position+1);
```

to

```
CNN i = objects.get(2 * position);
CNN i2 = objects.get(2 * position + 1);
```

By doing that, your adapter, will display in line 0, object at position 0 and 1 in your listview; then in line 1 object at position 2 and 3; etc ...

Comment: if object.size() is 25, the last item would not appear in the ListView.

Comment: Need to use two objects in getView() because have to pass values from two objects to the layout. The result output is shown in image. So every flip then, should show two items.. https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/lWtDfjyLGXAvVyHN1oDTO0M04auZfXr3/Screenshot_2015-10-06-14-02-25.png

Comment: Yes. That's why i say you need to assume that the list has an even number of datas. You can add +1 to return statement in `getCount` if the number of item is odd. But you will add to check in `getView`, before each `objects.get` that the position is not out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you for the quick Answer @sonic. Is there anyway to show an empty View so that only one item shown in the end.

Comment: Yes. You can check if the second object is `null` (i2 in your code). If not display the corresponding datas, else set null image in second image view and empty string as text in second text view.

Comment: Cannot check for null for i2 Checking that itself throws OutOfBound Error. Has to be done before object.get() method